# ASP.Net MVC Controller accepting "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, x-www-form-urlencoded

I inherited an old ASP.Net MVC web application. I need to modify it and add a page that can handle an incoming HTTP POST with hidden fields sent as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type. This page's URL will be provided as a webhook URL to an external system that will use it to send back the control to my application and will provide some data in the form of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

As I mentioned, this is an old MVC 5 application and is not targeting the .NET Core framework. Therefore I cannot declare my controller's method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public void Webhook([FromForm] Response webHookResponse)]
```

The "Consumes" and "FromForm" attributes are available in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" namespace, but I don't have access to that in my application. Is there a different way to handle this in MVC 5?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything. The DefaultModelBinder will bind your form values to the parameter object without specifying Consumes or FromForm attributes. The same is also true for .NET Core.

Edit - code for clarity:

Also an important note: this (automatic form binding) will only work if you do NOT have the [ApiController] attribute tagging your controller.

Assume you have three hidden fields coming in, one is named foo, the other is named fudge

Either one of these will work:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Webhook(string foo, string fudge)
{
}
```

or:

```
public class WbResponse
{
public string foo {get; set;}
public string fudge {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public void Webhook(WbResponse response)
{
}
```

Comment: can you post some code, to show what you mean by "bind your form values to the parameter object "? Are you saying that I should declare a type that has all the members I expect amongst the hidden fields and if I pass in an instance of that class, all members will auto-magically be populated with the values from the list of hidden fields? I will accept your answer if you explain what you meant in more details. I already found a solution which I posted below but I don't mind accepting yours

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am saying. I added code for clarity. here is an article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/february/asp-net-mvc-the-features-and-foibles-of-asp-net-mvc-model-binding

Comment: I tried and it worked with your suggestion as well. I accepted your answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the request object contains all the hidden fields in its "Form" member which is a NameValueCollection. I declared my method like this:

```
 // POST: /{Controller}/Webhook
 [HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult Webhook()
 {
    var requestFormFields = HttpContext.Request.Form;
```

and then I can access each field in the NameValueCollection by its name:

```
    var hiddenFieldValue = requestFormFields["hiddenFieldName"];
```